# Javascript/jQuery Tables Element Grabbing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a problem, I wish to grab the value thingy in a "td"
This is my code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I have tried giving them classes and onclick functions() but is there a way without creating a thousand or so functions and ids.

Comment: do you have any id or class to table and which td value you want to read?

Comment: at least there are 3 important requirements missing for this question, 1: when it triggered, 2: which td(s) value to retrieve, 3: expected output result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have onclick event handle on table (using id or class selector in jquery). See below code

```js
$(function(){ // this is to ensure if all DOM loaded
   $("#tableToRead td").on("click", function(){ // click handler for each td inside tableToRead table
     var value = $(this).text();// here $(this) refer to clicked td and using .text() gives text inside td.
     alert(value);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableToRead">
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation: add a single listener to the `table`, and then examine the `target` of all click events. If the clicked element matches a `td`, get the `textContent` of that `td`:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('td')) return;
  console.log('clicked on element with textContent: ' + target.textContent);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Ideally, give the one `table` an `id` so that you can select it by selecting that `id`, rather than using `querySelector('table')`, which will select the first `table` in your document, no matter what it is)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```js
$('#tbl').on('click','td',function(){
var myValue= $(this).html();
var prevValue=$(this).prev('td').html();
var nextValue=$(this).next('td').html();

alert('myvalue='+myValue+', prevValue='+prevValue+',nextValue='+nextValue+'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```